# Software development methodology for startup less than 3 friends

Tags: tdd, development-environment, agile, lifecycle

I am starting a project with 2 friends, we all are software developers and we want to do things in a **safe and right way**. That's why we decided to use some software development methodoly that fits our needs. I would like to know which could be a good starting point for us, and these are the variables:

- We are a team of 3.
- We are friends.
- This is a new company.
- We want to do things in the **right** way.
- We are looking to generate *clean code*.

I would also like to know of software that could help those methodologies.

Comment: That question seems like it should be on programmers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: thank you, if here doesn't work i will move it there.

Comment: I would rephrase that question and post it again. I think there is far more to that  than the one answer you got and I think there are lots of people interested in that topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple must have's to start *the right way*:

1. Continuous Integration - use a continuous integration server to build your code and run automated tests.  Jenkins is a great opensource example
2. Version Control - Git is the trendy new (and better) choice, but SVN works too.  FWIW, the organization where I work is moving from SVN to Git
3. Write lots of tests - It will save you time and headache in the long run
4. Work on something you are interested in.

Comment: Continuous Integration was a great idea, i will read about it.